# Jetty-9 warning: badMessage: 400 Illegal character

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I am using jetty-9.2.2 with CometD-3.0.1. I am seeing below warning in my setup. It comes ~4,5 times in a day.:

```
2014-08-28 08:50:53.712:WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp607635164-15194: badMessage: 
    400 Illegal character for HttpChannelOverHttp@5946f125{r=1,a=IDLE,uri=-}
```

There is no details that can be debugged from the warning message. I have already logged a request https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=443049 to provide detailed warning.

Meanwhile I want to know what is causing this warning? Can I ignore this or some messages are lost because of this?

Answer (score 55):

Change `https` to `http` in the url.

I had the same error, then found out it's because my application did not support https, so jetty cannot recognize the https encrypted request.

Comment: I spent more than 12 hours trying to figure out what the issue was. This works. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

**Update May 2017**

For Jetty 9.3+ users, you might see a log message that makes this response code more clear.

See [Header parse error after upgrade to Jetty 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300109/775715) for details.

**Original Answer**

The `Bad Message: 400 Illegal Character` can occur during parsing of a bad HTTP Request.

That is the HTTP error response that the client sees.

Some (not all) situations in which it can occur.

- The EOL is not "\r\n" (CR + LF) (HTTP spec requirement)
- The HTTP Method token is either not recognized or has invalid whitespace after it
- The HTTP Version is not recognized or has invalid characters
- HTTP Header name does not follow spec
- HTTP Header value does not follow spec

This message is common on public (internet facing) servers.

You have bad HTTP requests coming in.  Why?

- A legitimate HTTP client has a bug
- A legitimate HTTP client is not following the HTTP spec
- A non HTTP client attempted to connect to your server (such as attempting to use non-encrypted HTTP on a SSL/TLS/HTTPS port, or even something as odd as an SMTP/IMAP email client attempting to talk to your HTTP port)
- A malicious client is attempting to probe your system for weaknesses

Comment: Thanks but I was not seeing any error in old jettyv7.6. These errors started coming after updating my jetty server to 9.2.2. So is there any particular character in the request which was allowed previously but not now ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Jetty 7 vs Jetty 9, this level of HTTP error/warning was present in Jetty 7 as well.

Comment: In fact, Jetty 9 is more lenient with parsing (this is as a result of the work with the updated HTTP RFCs, WebSocket, and HTTP/2)

Comment: Can I ignore this warning ? In my use case I am deploying cometd in jetty. As discussed with CometD vendors, they are saying to ignore this warning.  : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cometd-users/V5Dn9np1zz0

Comment: Thanks for the comment on newlines (CRLF). Using unix2dos on the files on Windows fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 11):

This error can be caused, as it was for me, by a silly little mistake.

When testing on my localhost Jetty instance, I received a very similar 400 Illegal Character message. Then I realized why. I had simply assumed application address on my local Jetty was:

`https://localhost:8080`

whereas the correct address was unsecured:

`http://localhost:8080`

No problems after that.

Comment: Oops--I am sorry--I see that my answer has effectively already been given above by S. Du. This answer of mine perhaps should be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

Jetty is cautious about detailed error messages that include user sent data, as these can be part of an attack - even if echo'd just to a terminal.

However, we can do better and log some sanitised data.     Acting on the bugzilla

Answer (score 0):

Well, I met this problem because I mistook the "http://" as "https://"