# Illegal character 0x0 in state=START for buffer -- pyspark 2.0

Tags: pyspark

I am using sklearn library for some regression for each group of data what i have.

```
def func(keys, values):
 clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
 continued

rdd =df.rdd.map(lambda r :(Row(key1= r.key1, key2= r.key2), r))
           .groupByKey()\
           .flatMap(lambda kv: func(kv[0],kv[1]))
```

After the few minutes of execution i am getting below message, can any one help me to understand this?.

```
[Stage 242:====================================================>  (19 + 1) / 20]16/09/21 21:18:19 WARN HttpParser: Illegal character 0x0 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer@7d7a1efa[p=1,l=1,c=16384,r=0]={\x00<<<>>>ET /jobs/ HTTP/1....\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
  WARN HttpParser: Illegal character 0x0 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer@52c2806e[p=1,l=1,c=16384,r=0]={\x00<<<>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
   WARN HttpParser: badMessage: 400 Illegal character 0x0 for HttpChannelOverHttp@eebf595{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}
   WARN HttpParser: badMessage: 400 Illegal character 0x0 for   HttpChannelOverHttp@199d7092{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}

 [Stage 259:==================================================>    (59 + 5) / 64]16/09/21 21:24:51 WARN HttpParser: Illegal character 0x0 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer@52c2806e[p=1,l=1,c=16384,r=0]={\x00<<<>>>ET /jobs/HTTP/1....\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}

 16/09/21 21:24:51 WARN HttpParser: badMessage: 400 Illegal character 0x0 for HttpChannelOverHttp@27f44836{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to connect via HTTPS to HTTP port or vice versa as per [Jetty-9 warning: badMessage: 400 Illegal character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625410/jetty-9-warning-badmessage-400-illegal-character)