# Jetty - Error on start - PicketLinkServletContextListener.isHttpSecurityEnabled - NullPointerException

Tags: java, http, https, jetty, war

I'm trying to start Jetty with my Webapp, but I'm facing a strange error.

Facts:

- I'm using IntelliJ and starting Jetty from IDE
- My webapp produce a War
- I'm not trying to use Jetty with HTTPS
- My webapp runs on Wildfly 9.0.2 with any problem
- Log shows the loading of my caches, beans and Spring configurations.
- I hadn't change anything directly inside Jetty, just made some configurations on InteliJ
- Jetty Version: 9.4.0v20161208
- I have this Jetty modules activated:

  1. home-base-warning
  2. ext
  3. server
  4. jsp
  5. resources
  6. deploy
  7. jstl
  8. websocket
  9. http
  10. plus
  11. jndi
  12. client
  13. logging-jetty
- I have a database drivers for H2, Teradata and MSSQL in my /ext folder
- After the exception shown below, there is another strange error related with HTTP parse. Please, look at the end of the log.
- Error:

  ```
  14:46:58.459 [Scanner-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 22631 ms
  2017-06-27 14:46:58.459:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Scanner-1: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@23241e15{/mywebapp,[file:///C:/Users/username/IdeaProjects/mywebapp/target/mywebapp/, jar:file:///C:/Users/username/IdeaProjects/mywebapp/target/mywebapp/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-swagger-ui-2.7.0.jar!/META-INF/resources],UNAVAILABLE}
  java.lang.NullPointerException
      at org.picketlink.http.internal.PicketLinkServletContextListener.isHttpSecurityEnabled(PicketLinkServletContextListener.java:80)
      at org.picketlink.http.internal.PicketLinkServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PicketLinkServletContextListener.java:56)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:865)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:828)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1480)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1442)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:788)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:540)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:458)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
      at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
      at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
  [2017-06-27 02:46:58,932] Artifact mywebapp:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
  [2017-06-27 02:46:58,932] Artifact mywebapp:war exploded: Deploy took 31.279 milliseconds
  2017-06-27 14:46:59.544:WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp985934102-25: Illegal character 0x16 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer@3219b4b4[p=1,l=197,c=8192,r=196]={\x16<<<\x03\x01\x00\xC0\x01\x00\x00\xBc\x03\x03\xB8\x86,2\xCe\xC6\xD7...\x00\x08\x8a\x8a\x00\x1d\x00\x17\x00\x18::\x00\x01\x00>>>; q=.2\r\nConnectio...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
  2017-06-27 14:46:59.545:WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp985934102-25: bad HTTP parsed: 400 Illegal character 0x16 for HttpChannelOverHttp@771b3c93{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}
  2017-06-27 14:46:59.663:WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp985934102-47: Illegal character 0x16 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer@5e1ed496[p=1,l=197,c=8192,r=196]={\x16<<<\x03\x01\x00\xC0\x01\x00\x00\xBc\x03\x03\xDe\xB7\xFf\xC4\xCdZ\xD8...\x00\x08\xBa\xBa\x00\x1d\x00\x17\x00\x18\xCa\xCa\x00\x01\x00>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}
  2017-06-27 14:46:59.663:WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp985934102-47: bad HTTP parsed: 400 Illegal character 0x16 for HttpChannelOverHttp@2ff19611{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}
  ```

Do you have any idea of how to solve it?

Do you need any further information? Please, let me know.

Comment: Use a recent stable release. Don't deploy in jetty-distribution (see warning it gives you). Don't change content in jetty-distribution. Create a proper `jetty.base` instance directory. [Your parser warnings is due to someone connecting to an http port using https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625410/jetty-9-warning-badmessage-400-illegal-character). NPE is in your code, not Jetty (need more details about what your code is expecting)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I'd tried now with 9.4.6.v20170531 and unfortunately nothing changed. 

Sorry but what do you mean not changing jetty-distribution? I'd just add the container as server in IntelliJ and configured the modules and build artifacts.

About HTTP error: Thanks! I'll take a better look right now.

Answer (score 0):

PicketLink uses CDI.

Jetty does not ship with CDI support.

You'll have to install Weld/CDI into your webapp for CDI support in Jetty.

Comment: Perfect! I added CDI module and had an annotation error after that. Then added Annotation module and now I'm with the same error as before.

Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Testing a little bit I figured out that if I exclude picketlink dependency, everything goes just fine. 
Unfortunately I need the lib. 
I was using version 2.7.0 and tested with the latest one (2.7.1) but the error still happens. Do you know any incompatibility of Jetty with Picketlink?

Comment: Its not an incompatibility.  Picketlink needs CDI.  You need to add CDI support to your webapp (add weld and configure it).

Comment: I thought that enabling CDI as a module in Jetty would be enough. My app runs perfect with Wildfly, using picketlink, spring mvc + security.  So do I need to configure CDI even with my spring's app? This looks strange to me, but I believe you.

Thanks for the hint, I'll search how to do it and try.

Comment: cdi module is for server side, not webapp side. (such as having a server component handling sessions, or datasources that need cdi).  Jetty is a Web Container. CDI is not part of the Web Container spec.  Again, add weld to your webapp and configure it.